# Django - Static images do not load, throw 404 error in console

Tags: django

I've been trying to solve this error for a very long time. I have a lot of static images that I am trying to open through my website. However, none of the static images will load, and when I look in the console, I see the error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have ran `collectstatic`  multiple times, restarted the server, done everything.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
import posts.views
import sitepages.views
import hackathons.views
import projects.views
import skills.views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('blog/', posts.views.blog, name = "blog"),
    #path('posts/<int:post_id>/', posts.views.post_details, name="post_details"),
    path('about/', sitepages.views.about,name="about"),
    path('awards/',sitepages.views.awards,name="awards"),
    path('skills/',skills.views.skills,name="skills"),
    path('skills/<int:skill_id>/', skills.views.skill_details,name="skill_details"),
    path('projects/',projects.views.project,name="projects"),
    path('hackathons/',hackathons.views.hackathons,name="hackathons"),
    path('',sitepages.views.home,name="home"),
    #path('hobbies/',sitepages.views.hobbies,name="hobbies"),
    path('internships/',sitepages.views.internships,name="internships"),
    path('project_details/<int:project_id>/', projects.views.project_details,name="project_details"),
    path('hackathon_details/<int:hackathon_id>/', hackathons.views.hackathon_details, name="hackathon_details")
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Static section of settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for pranavblog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True




# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'posts',
    'sitepages',
    'hackathons',
    'projects',
    'pagedown',
    'skills.apps.SkillsConfig',
    'django.forms'
]
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pranavblog.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pranavblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
SITE_ID = 1

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Above is the whole settings.py, as requested. Allowed hosts and secret key were left out on purpose.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Edit:
Here is my project folder structure. The media folder contains a lot of images.
[image]

Comment: If the user account running the app doesn't have access to the folder something like this might result. When I first set up my server I had problems with the 'collectstatic' command. Unless I owned the 'static' folder, I couldn't 'collectstatic', but if I owned the 'static' directory, the files would not get served.

Comment: try `DEBUG = True`

Comment: Also, @Atcrank, I have full permissions for the entire server running on my VPS. I can collectstatic without any errors, but every time I do, it tells me that it has no new static files to collect even if I have new additions. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi again. I would check who the process owner/group for your app and for any server application (uwsgi / nginx etc) upstream while its running. The process owner/group is not necessarily you.  Another very useful thing to look at is to use the 'inspect' mode of the browser to see the actual request that has 404ed. Sometimes I've had bugs because my template had a leading or trailing slash in the wrong place, causing the 404.  The full stack trace might be helpful to post.

Comment: The error I receive in the console is 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. Does that help? I do not know where to get a full stack trace from.

Answer (score 1):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: This does not do anything on my local machine or the host VPN server.

Comment: I actually have another question - all the images are present in my media folder, but none of them are in my static folder. Do you know how I can get the files from my media folder to my static folder properly?

Comment: It also seems like the website is trying to get files from the media folder. However, many of the files which I uploaded to my website are not in the media folder. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Or maybe not, but that's the only thing I can see you don't have in your settings.

Comment: Can you post your project folder structure please?!

Comment: I have added the structure into the original question via an edit. Please tell me if you need any more information.

Comment: @PranavE the only I can see is that you're still missing `static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in your URLs after the `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` append that line I've said.

Comment: Just one more thing: Are you running through Gunicorn + Nginx locally?

Comment: No. I have an external VPS which runs ubuntu 16.0.4, and I have gunicorn and nginx on that.

Comment: Also, I have tried appending  the line. It has not yet solved the problem.

Comment: This did not work either. I actually have another question - all the images are present in my media folder, but none of them are in my static folder. Do you know how I can get the files from my media folder to my static folder properly? It also seems like the website is trying to get files from the media folder. However, many of the files which I uploaded to my website are not in the media folder. Do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178751/discussion-between-higor-rossato-and-pranav-e).

Answer (score 0):

You've added a path to serve MediaFiles, not Static Files. You might want to add `static(settings. STATIC_URL,document_root=settings. STATIC_ROOT)` to your urls.py

Do not use DEBUG=True in production, that is a big "No". 
Have you considered using a proxy like NGINX ? You'll be able to cache your static files improving perfomance. Django is not designed to serve Static files.

Comment: I actually use Nginx on my external VPS, along with Gunicorn. I'm only using debug=true to test if that was the problem on my site.

Comment: OK, in your NGINX conf did you had your route to serve statics ?
Something like : 
    }
    location /$YOUR_STATIC_URL/ {
        alias                   /$PATH_TO_YOUR_STATIC_FOLDER/;
    }

Comment: Yes, Julien. I have configured nginx and gunicorn according to tutorials, and verified that it works. However, the issue is that whenever I upload new static images via models, the entire page's static stops working. I collectstatic, restart nginx and gunicorn, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: That's odd... What does the Nginx says ? The HTTP header is 404 or 403?
Might be rigths that might need fix

Comment: When I say the entire page's static stops working, I mean that the website loads fine, but none of the images load and I get errors in console.

Comment: OK have you tried opening rights to your Media folder ?
Nginx should have access to those if you want to serve files.
Can you do an ls -a on your projects root folder?

Comment: Julien, thank you for all your help so far. I decided to just convert the website to pure HTML so it would run statically, and avoid all the problems with Django. Thank you for your help so far.